# clearing SMB credentials on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, samba, smb, freenas

I have tried `net use * /DEL` to no avail, says cannot find anything, tried `net use \\server /del` to no avail, and the credentials don't show up on the credential manager either. This PC has read permissions to my samba share even though guest access is disabled on FreeNAS. Reboots don't solve this either.

Windows technet forums don't even read my posts and reply with canned responses for stuff I already tried.
Short of deleting my samba share and changing the IP, has anyone found a solution to this problem? I see multiple users with no solution other than the stuff that I know doesn't work.

Comment: Press the Windows key + R together to open the Run box. Type the following command and hit Enter:rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr. See if the credential is stored here.

Answer (score 0):

Try ending the explorer.exe process in task manager and running it again.

[image]

Press the windows key + R and type **explorer.exe** and hit enter

That should clear the session credentials.

Comment: This has not worked either, but it did eventually just "fix itself".
This is quite frustrating, still.